# how to center buttons and make small spacing between them

Tags: html, css

I need to place a button in the center of the div but also I need space between those buttons here is an example of what I need [image: 1]

and here what I have [image: 2]

DEMO

```css
.panelRegister {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22%;
  width: 1120px;
  height: 806px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panelRegister .btn_styleRegister {
  background-color: RGB(41,127,182);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Register/stageRegister.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body> 
   <div id="click_Register" class="panelRegister">
      <h1 style="color: black;  margin-left: 20px;">Register</h1>
      <div class="center">
      <button class="btn_Register btn_styleRegister">Manager/Doctor</button>
      <button class=" btn_styleRegister">Family/Resident</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I need help with space between buttons I tried with justify-content:space between but it puts a big space between buttons

Comment: you can try justify-content:space-evenly or space-around, setting some fixed height

Comment: You can also add something like `margin: 10px;` to your buttons. Or setting `gap: 10px;` for `.center`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `margin` for the buttons

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
  /* Flexbox */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column
}

button {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <button>Button One</button>
  <button>Button Two</button>
</div>
```

in your code it would be like this (I also removed the `display: none;` so you can see it):

```css
.panelRegister {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22%;
  width: 1120px;
  height: 806px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panelRegister .btn_styleRegister {
  background-color: RGB(41,127,182);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Register/stageRegister.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body> 
   <div id="click_Register" class="panelRegister">
      <h1 style="color: black;  margin-left: 20px;">Register</h1>
      <div class="center">
      <button class="btn_Register btn_styleRegister">Manager/Doctor</button>
      <button class=" btn_styleRegister">Family/Resident</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap classes instead of css, it will automatically add spaces, colors, size etc.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn_Register btn_styleRegister btn-sm">Manager/Doctor</button>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
     <button class=" btn_styleRegister btn-sm">Family/Resident</button>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panelRegister {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22%;
  width: 1120px;
  height: 806px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panelRegister .btn_styleRegister {
  background-color: RGB(41,127,182);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.btn_styleRegister{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Register/stageRegister.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body> 
   <div id="click_Register" class="panelRegister">
      <h1 style="color: black;  margin-left: 20px;">Register</h1>
      <div class="center">
      <button class="btn_Register btn_styleRegister">Manager/Doctor</button>
      <button class=" btn_styleRegister">Family/Resident</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```